# How can I search case sensitive online

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to search online for the string `toUri()`.

Valid result will be Java's [Path.toUri()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toUri())

But when I search google it return **mostly** `toURI` results.

When I search I discover that [search engines don't support case sensitive search](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-case-sensitive-search-engine).

How can I still ignore results of `toURI`? Searching `"toUri()" - "toURI()"` didn't help.

Comment: Just provide more context. You’re looking for JavaScript help? Search for `javascript touri`.

Comment: add details,search for Path.toUri()

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for making a case-sensitive search on google. You might add relevant words so that only the one that you want to search for, appears on results.

If you'd like to filter something from your results that isn't spelled the same as your query you could use hyphen(-) symbol.

Eg:

> blender -software

will yield results about the blender machine instead of the software blender that is used for 3d modelling.

Comment: Still not help my proble, toUri -toURI not working

Comment: try including terms related to "toUri" and excluding terms related to "toURI" using hyphen

Comment: Tried it . see updated question

Answer (score 0):

Here's help from Google itself.  You can do this with Chrome too.

The Find bar (Ctrl + F) in Firefox offers a “Match Case” option to help you perform case-sensitive searches on a web page. If you type “RAM” in the find box, the browser will only highlight the phrase “RAM” on that page and not Ram or ram.

Comment: How is working in chrome? is it an addon? and still I get alot of irrelevant results and I need to page through